# changing TabStop in SelectedIndexChanged runs too late

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I've got a call log form with multiple ComboBox controls.

To speed up data entry default values are chosen for some fields based off previous fields.  Some of these default values are very likely to be true so I'd like the defaulted field to be completely skipped in the tab order.

For example the username field sets the value of the membership type field.  If the user is a member then the membership ComboBox will always be member so it shouldn't be a TabStop, but if the username is "non member" there are a few choices, so it should be a TabStop.

In the username's SelectedIndexChanged event I have logic to set the TabStop of the membership type but because membership type is the next field after username setting them here is too late.  The tab processing has already begun and the focused field will be set to membership type no matter what the TabStop on that field is.

I can't use the focus events because they also fire when the user click on the field and it should still activate then.  Only tabbing should be effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some fiddleing I came up with the following solution but I couldn't find anything posted on this before so I'm posting it in case it helps someone else. I'm overriding ProccessTabKey on the form level to check if WinForms screwed up.

```
protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
{
    //find out where we are
    Control startingFocus = this.ActiveControl;

    //go to the next control
    SelectNextControl(startingFocus, forward, true, true, true);

    //find out if we still wanted to go there, (tabstop might have been changed in a SelectedIndexChanged)
    Control newNext = GetNextControl(startingFocus, forward);
    while (!newNext.TabStop)
    {
        newNext = GetNextControl(newNext, forward);
    }

    //if we are in the wrong place, move to the right place
    if (this.ActiveControl != newNext)
    {
        newNext.Focus();
    }

    return true;
}
```